# Dynamic tablename in teradata create statement

Tags: etl, teradata, data-warehouse, teradata-sql-assistant, wherescape-red

I am trying to create a dynamic table name using the following procedure in WhereScape RED:

```
SELECT CAST(CURRENT_DATE as  format 'YYYYMMDD') into v_date;

    SET v_tname =  'Anirban_Test' || v_date ||'030' ;

    CREATE MULTISET TABLE [TABLEOWNER].[(SELECT * from v_tname)] NO FALLBACK ,
     NO BEFORE JOURNAL,
     NO AFTER JOURNAL,
     CHECKSUM = DEFAULT,
     DEFAULT MERGEBLOCKRATIO 
     (
      TARGET_JOB_NAME VARCHAR(50) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC NOT NULL)
      UNIQUE PRIMARY INDEX UP_LOAD_PROTOCOL ( TARGET_JOB_NAME );
```

But the create statement is not working. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you you give us more details of the error message?

Comment: I don't know anything about wherescape red, but that is simply not valid DDL.  The only way you can do any sort of dynamic SQL in Teradata is in a stored procedure.

Comment: You can't SELECT from v_tname because that's a scalar variable not a table. And you can't use a variable reference as part of a name. You will have to create a text string for the statement (concatenating the fixed and variable parts), then submit that string for execution, e.g. using EXECUTE IMMEDIATE in a stored procedure.

Comment: @Fred I tried the approach and it is successful now. Thanks a lot :)